# Построение изобат по данным из csv файла

Tags: python, matplotlib

Как преобразовать  набор данных в файле .csv в виде:

```
 - 316925.000 8354725.000 -40.06
   316935.000 8354615.000 -40.02
   316935.000 8354625.000 -39.96
   316935.000 8354635.000 -39.97
   316935.000 8354645.000 -39.97
   316935.000 8354655.000 -39.98
   316935.000 8354665.000 -40.01
   316935.000 8354675.000 -40.09
   316935.000 8354685.000 -40.15
   316935.000 8354695.000 -40.15
   316935.000 8354705.000 -40.11
   316935.000 8354715.000 -40.07
   316935.000 8354725.000 -40.03
   316945.000 8354595.000 -39.96
   316945.000 8354605.000 -39.87
```

В файл Geo tiff горизонтали с подписями каждые 5 и 10 метров. Единственное что я нашёл[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://alex.miller.im/posts/contour-plots-in-python-matplotlib-x-y-z/
Но как объединить этот код в единое решение с выгрузкой результата в файл .dxf пока не знаю.

Comment: вообще, у вас в заголовке один вопрос, а в теле вопроса - два других. вам что нужно? 1) построить изобары, 2) выгрузить csv в geotiff, 3) выгрузить csv в dxf?

Comment: Построить изобаты с заданным шагом и выгрузить их в geotiff

Answer (score 0):

Ну собственно, построить изолинии в матплотлиб не так у ж и сложно:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("1.csv", header=None)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 14))

xi = np.linspace(df[0].min()-1, df[0].max()+1, 100)
yi = np.linspace(df[1].min()-1, df[1].max()+1, 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
zi = griddata((df[0], df[1]), df[2], (xi, yi), method='linear')

levels = np.linspace(df[2].min(), df[2].max(), 6)

cs = ax.contour(xi, yi, zi, levels=levels)
ax.clabel(cs, cs.levels, inline=True, fontsize=10)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.savefig("iso.png")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что касается выгрузки в GeoTiff - тут я готовой библиотеки не нашел, а вот в dxf выгрузить можно. сначала только нужно установить модуль ezdxf. Единственное, с обозначением изолиний уж разбирайтесь сами, и перед выгрузкой отключите ax.clabel (закомментируйте), иначе в полилиниях будут пробелы:

```
import ezdxf
from ezdxf import colors
from ezdxf.enums import TextEntityAlignment
doc = ezdxf.new(dxfversion="R2010")

doc.layers.add("LAYER1", color=colors.RED)
msp = doc.modelspace()

idx=0

for item in cs.collections:
    for i in item.get_paths():
        v = i.vertices
        z = [levels[idx]]*len(v)
        msp.add_lwpolyline(v, dxfattribs={'color': idx, "elevation": levels[idx]})
    idx+=1
        
doc.saveas("test1.dxf")
```

получите такое (плоские полилинии с параметром elevation равным координатам Z контура):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению я застопорился на этапе просто построить график по координатам из примера:
xi = np.linspace(df[0].min()-1, df[0].max()+1, 100)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Выгрузка в DXF это сверх задача на которую да же не рассчитывал, огромное спасибо! Но как во второй пример загрузить мои данные из файла .csv ?

Comment: судя по ошибке, у вас данные в датафрейме загрузились не как числа, а как строки. можете в своему вопросу присоединить ссылку на свой csv (фрагмент).

Comment: и это не второй пример - весь мой ответ - это одно целое, потому что для выгрузки в dxf используются контуры, полученные в первой части моего ответа.

Comment: Для файла csv я использовал данные с вопроса просто сохранив их в формат csv.:
   316935.000 8354635.000 -39.97
   316935.000 8354645.000 -39.97
   316935.000 8354655.000 -39.98
   316935.000 8354665.000 -40.01
   316935.000 8354675.000 -40.09
   316935.000 8354685.000 -40.15
   316935.000 8354695.000 -40.15
Насчёт выгрузки в dxf - именно этот этап я и не могу понять как использовать второй пример кода, я работаю в стандартном IDLE 3.8  просто компилируя Ваши примеры. Огромное спасибо за помощь.

Comment: я же тоже взял ваши данные из вопроса, сохранил из в csv и загрузил. где-то у вас ошибка, раз данные из csv не воспринимаются как числа.

Comment: Большое спасибо, я нашёл ошибку - изменив стурктуру csv добавив разделитель ",". Как же теперь мне полученный результат выгрузить в DXF создав один проект с расширение .py ?

Comment: ну так вам оба куска кода из моего ответа нужно просто собрать в один файл и все.

Comment: Огромное Вам Спасибо!

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, пометьте его как принятый.

Comment: Вот как бы ещё задать шаг основной и вспомогательной изолинии с подпись как на примере (по центру)...

Comment: в первой части кода есть переменная `levels` - сейчас она просто делит расстояние от минимального до максимального значения на 6 частей. вы можете вручную задать ей список значений в нужном количеству либо вычислять их так, как вам нужно.

Comment: Не примите за наглость. Ваша помощь - бесценна и даёт много "пищи" для самообразования. Но не подскажите как для вышеописанных целей адаптировать библиотеку: seaborn.kdeplot
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html ? Цель - получить гораздо плавные не резанные изолинии.

Comment: я боюсь, kdeplot вам не поможет, поскольку библиотека разработана для оценки ядерной плотности. у вас же ax.contour не просто что-то рисует, а вычисляет контуры. есть подозрение, что плавность отсутствует из-за исходных данных

Comment: По идее используют триангуляцию делоне - которая интерполирует исходные данные в узловых точках по длине ребра. Но эта задача уровня полноценной ГИС. Меня устроили простые сплайновые кривые...

Comment: ничто не мешает вам получить контуры из ax.contour и "скормить№ их kdeplot. но это в любом случае тем для отдельного вопроса.

Comment: Понял Вас . Но простите моё невежество: Не могу понять каким образом Вы задаёте пределы фрейма функцией (np.linspace(df[0].min()-1, df[0].max()+1, 100)) - Почему именно эти параметры?